# Changing font in R Markdown to Times New Roman

Tags: fonts, r-markdown

I'm writing a report for uni and it's specified that we have to use Times New Roman. R-Markdown reports look so much nicer than word in my opinion, but  I can't seem to change the font.
This is at the top of my document:

```
output: pdf_document
bibliography: miniproject.bib
fontsize: 11pt
mainfont: Times New Roman
geometry: margin=2.5cm
```

I'm not getting any errors or an unused argument warning when I knit, but the font doesn't seem to be changing.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, @Bex Middleton. Try changing `Times New Roman` to `"Times New Roman"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may work for you:

````
---
title: "Times"
author: "bttomio"
date: "October 18, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

Another option:

````
---
title: "Times"
author: "bttomio"
date: "October 18, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: "Times New Roman"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it's working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you. @BexMiddleton, could please accept/confirm my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, is there a reason why this would work for a pdf_document output and not for a word_document output?